# What is the best way to create a security log and dispay a visual dialog box in a Windows service?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-services

I am creating a Windows service in visual studios using c# and I need to create a Windows application/security log event and then alert the user through a visual dialog box when a certain thing happens. How would I go about this since a Windows service has no UI and cannot interact with the desktop?

Comment: Message Box Class for alerts: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messagebox(v=vs.110).aspx   and event logs: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/307024/how-to-write-to-an-event-log-by-using-visual-c

Comment: By definition, this will be a standalone application as services are not permitted to interact with the desktop... but this question is too broad, shows no research and will probably be closed.

Comment: Probably  a key part of your standalone app: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlog.entrywritten(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @MarshallTigerus Windows Security prevents desktop interaction from any services. You would need to implement some kind of RPC to another application that can display the message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Windows Service doesn't have the capability to interact with the desktop. The best you can do is to add in some kind of RPC functionality and have a desktop application.

Ideally this should be an application, such as a Tray/Notification Application.  Using WCF you can notify the tray application and that can then display the notification.

Logging, to file and the event log can be done with in the actual windows service.